# Compute $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Compute $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}} dx$.

For the definition of the contour integral we have 
$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(x)) \ \gamma'(x) dx$
where $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb C$ is a curve.

We note $\gamma(x) = ix$ and $\gamma'(x) = i$ with $0 \le x \le 2\pi$ and $f(z) = e^{e^z}$.
Then
$$
\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}} i \ dx
$$
from which we have 
$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}} dx = \frac 1i \int_\gamma f(z) dz
= \frac 1i \int_\gamma e^{e^z} dz$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}} dx &=  
\frac 1i \int_\gamma e^{e^z} dz\\ &=
\frac{2\pi}{i2\pi} \int_\gamma \frac{e^w}{w}dw \ \ \ \ \text{(Cauchy's integral formula)} \\ &=
2 \pi e^0 = 2 \pi  
\end{align*}
$$
where $w = e^z$ and $dw = e^z dz = w dz$.

Is this complex u-substitution with $w$ okay here? If it is okay, why can I use it here, and if not why not and what should I do instead?

Comment: With $\gamma =\{|z|=1\}$, $ \gamma(x )= e^{i x},z = \gamma(x), dz = \gamma'(x)dx = i e^{ix}dx$ you get $\int_{|z|=1} f(z)dz = \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{ix}) i e^{ix}dx$. Thus the $f$ you need to choose is not $e^z$.

Comment: @reuns What is $f(z)$ here? I think I'm misunderstanding, it looks like $f(z) = e^z$. Also I can't see exactly how this integral is the same as the original. Thanks.

Comment: $\int_\gamma e^z dz = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}} i e^{ix} dx$ which is not what you want

Comment: @reuns Okay right, I'm look at what I wrote and it's wrong, not what I intended, let me edit that. Ah that would be a far nicer integral to have though since it would be zero I think.

Comment: What do you not understand with  : $\gamma = \{|z| = 1\}$ traversed in positive direction ie. $$\gamma(x) = e^{ix}, x \in [0,2\pi] \qquad \implies \qquad \int_{\gamma} f(z)dz = \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{ix}) i e^{ix}dx$$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're pointing out why $f(z) = e^z$ is not the correct guess for $f$ (because of what you showed)? I can see that, so in my edited post I choose $f(z)=e^{e^z}$ with $\gamma(x) = ix$ for $x \in [0, 2\pi]$, which I think works. Or maybe you're pointing out something else.

Comment: $0 \to 2i\pi$ is not a closed contour so it doesn't simplify anything. That's why you need to use the contour I mentioned : the unit circle in positive direction.

Comment: Then to fulfill that equation and the given integral choose $f(z) = \frac{e^z}{iz}$?

Comment: Exactly. Then how do you compute $\int_\gamma f(z)dz $

Comment: Use Cauchy's integral formula, $$\int_\gamma f(z) dz = \frac 1i \int_\gamma \frac{e^z}{z-0} dz = 2\pi e^0.$$ I see, thanks! I also very much misused Cauchy's integral formula in my post, by not using it on a closed path, which is quite sad.

Comment: Right. Now other question : can you evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}}dx=\int_0^{2\pi} (\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{k!})dx$ directly ? (Fourier series, $\int\sum= \sum \int$)